# How to change default order of products in search result page (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

I have been using **Solarium search module**. The solarium module returns the correct search results in the order of relevance and is stored in **'catalogsearch_result'** . The problem is that they are displayed in a random order and not according to relevance. So I need to change the order of products in search results page. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Which order you want to set, can you explain in detail.

Comment: @SHPatel I need the results in the order of relevance